# Using CustomSenderKmsKey in the AWS Cognito CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk, aws-userpools

I am configuring a Cognito User Pool using the CDK.
In the UserPool constructor, there is a `custom_sender_kms_key` attribute that is set to None by default.

The documentation states that :
This key will be used to encrypt temporary passwords and authorization codes that Amazon Cognito generates. Default: - No key ID configured.

I don't know if I should configure this or not. I'm not sure what it is used for. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using custom lambda to send the email and sms, you would not need to configure the key.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-sender-triggers.html